# I want the QED symbol to be 1 line lower at the end of proof

Tags: amsthm

Just as my title says, I would prefer to have my qed symbol to be 1 line lower than the last line of my proof. By default its on the same line and aligned to the right.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: See below code for an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    Hello there good chap! I'll put in another line here just to be sure its clear what I mean.
\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endproof}
  {\popQED}
  {\par\popQED}
  {}
  {}
```

In this way we patch the `proof` environment (its end part `\endproof`) to issue a `\par` before printing the qed symbol.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endproof}
  {\popQED}
  {\par\popQED}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    Hello there good chap! I'll put in another line here just to be sure its clear what I mean.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @BallzofFury You're welcome, happy to help.

Comment: This way it can jump to the next page at a page break I'm afraid... maybe something like `\relax\ifhmode\\\else\par\fi\popQED` ?

Comment: @tohecz no, this doesn't work. Maybe `\nopagebreak[4]\par\popQED` is better

Comment: @karlkoeller It was just a shot in the darkness. That one should work probably. Another option might be redefining `\qedsymbol` to occupy the whole line width.

Comment: @tohecz And, anyway, the normal behavior of the qed is to jump on the next page. Try this document: `\lipsum[1-6] aaa \begin{proof} Hello there good chap! I'll put in another line here just to be sure its clear whats. \end{proof}`

Comment: @karlkoeller -- the example is using `amsthm`.  if the proof ends with a display, it already drops down a line (plus the post-display skip); with this new approach, it is dropped even further, so even if it does stay on the same page, there will be a huge gap.  and `\qedhere` doesn't work.  maybe testing to see whether you're already in vertical mode, and *not* adding more space there would take care of that problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\qedhere` works as expected and in presence of a displayed math, no more space is added.

Comment: @karlkoeller -- but that's not what's been requested.  `\qedhere` will continue to put the tombstone on the "last" line of a proof-ending display (which may be centered vertically, if `split` or `aligned` is used) and happily overwrite a right-hand equation number unless a starred version suppresses the numbers.  the question explicitly asks for a one-line drop. (not that i agree with this, mind you, but it's what was requested.)

Answer (score 8):

Don't do it. In most cases the tombstone will hang from nowhere.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% lower the symbol and make it zero width
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\llap{\openbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof that this setting is \emph{really bad}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case you have a proof which is less than 1 line, I understand what you mean. But I find this doesn't happen too often.

Comment: @BallzofFury One line or more is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems sufficient (not thoroughly tested) to issue a `\par\nobreak` before the "QED paragraph" is set:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,xpatch}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd{\qed}{\leavevmode}{\par\nobreak\leavevmode}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}
Some more text.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```